# url mapping from html to aspx

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I want to redirect some html page to aspx.
I try this in my web.config like below:

```
  　<urlMappings enabled="true">
　　<add url="~/report.html" mappedUrl="~/page.aspx?id=2"/>
   <add url="~/product.html" mappedUrl="~/products.aspx?type=all"/>
　　</urlMappings>
```

but it doesn't work, is I thinking got something wrong?

Is there any better idea except to create html files and set the meta refresh?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

By default IIS won't run .html pages through the aspnet engine. You'll have to configure the server to pass all requests through the aspnet engine as mentioned in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2538/URL-Rewriting-with-ASP-NET in the Finally section.